# Java: Variable holder and its value?

Tags: java, variables, int

I'm having a tough time understanding something from one of my exercises in a book(Complete beginner).

The example code was to make a guessing game with three players and it generates a random int for all three players which has to come out the same as the randomly generated int by the game.

The code contains three classes, but this is the most important one where I have a question. The other two are just GameLauncher class and Player(The one that plays against the other three players) class.

```
public class GuessGame {

Player p1;
Player p2;
Player p3;

public void startGame(){
    p1 = new Player();
    p2 = new Player();
    p3 = new Player();

    int guessp1 = 10;
    int guessp2 = 0;
    int guessp3 = 0;

    boolean p1isRight = false;
    boolean p2isRight = false;
    boolean p3isRight = false;

    int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 9...");

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Number to guess is "+targetNumber);

        p1.guess();
        p2.guess();
        p3.guess();

        guessp1 = p1.number;
        System.out.println("Player one has guessed " + guessp1);
        guessp2 = p2.number;
        System.out.println("Player two has guessed " + guessp2);
        guessp3 = p3.number;
        System.out.println("Player three has guessed " + guessp3);

        if (guessp1 == targetNumber) {
            p1isRight = true;

        }if (guessp2 == targetNumber){
            p2isRight=true;

        }if (guessp3 == targetNumber){
            p3isRight=true;
        }
        if (p1isRight||p2isRight||p3isRight){
            System.out.println("We have a winner!");
            System.out.println("Player one got it right? " + p1isRight);
            System.out.println("Player two got it right?" + p2isRight);
            System.out.println("Player three got it right? " + p3isRight);
            System.out.println("The game is over.");
            break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("None of you got it right! Try again!");
        }
    }
}

}
```

From the above code:

```
    int guessp1 = 10;
    int guessp2 = 0;
    int guessp3 = 0;
```

is the one that I don't understand. Originally, all of them are assigned the value 0. I tried to assign 10 to see what would happen, but nothing changed. The game played out just the same.

My question is, what is the significance for the value assigned to a declared integer if any at all? Especially in this situation.

Excluding normal uses like say just printing it or manipulating it with math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later in your routine you override the assigned value int the following code lines:

```
 guessp1 = p1.number;
 System.out.println("Player one has guessed " + guessp1);
 guessp2 = p2.number;
 System.out.println("Player two has guessed " + guessp2);
 guessp3 = p3.number;
 System.out.println("Player three has guessed " + guessp3);
```

So basically the assigned value is not beeing uset at all, but usually a good practice implies setting a default values to variables so on later use you can determine if a value was assigned or the variable still has its default value.

Defining a default value helps to avoid unexpected situations, In some programming languages created objects which was not assigned or set to null could have any garbage data according to the memory address they reference.

Some use a values like -1 where only positive numbers are expected and catch such a case where no value was assigned by asking if the default value still there or not. In your case the default value is 0.

Comment: Oh, so once I override them with the number created by p1.number, the original value loses all of it's value, and is just used to perform the printing command?

Comment: Ok, so I just tried and 

   System.out.println("Player one has guessed " + p1.number);

works just the same without 
guesspp1.number;
But, what you are saying is that this nullifies the possibility of me verifying that there was input?

Comment: You can set guessp1  to -1 and check between the lines if (guessp1  != -1) this would mean that a value was assigned.